# Why am i getting ConcurrentModificationException on this unmodifiableSet?

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I'm getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on the line where the for-loop starts (see comment in code).

Why am i getting ConcurrentModificationException on this unmodifiableSet?

```
final Set<Port> portSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(node.getOpenPorts());
if (!portSet.isEmpty()) {
    StringBuilder tmpSb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Port pp : portSet) { // <------- exception happening here
        tmpSb.append(pp.getNum()).append("  ");
    }
}
```

I've never witnessed this, but I'm getting crash reports from Google.

Comment: Can the `Set` returned by `node.getOpenPorts()` be modified by other code (not necessarily your own code)?

Comment: ok. i guess my assumption of `Collections.unmodifiableSet` making a copy of the set is wrong. I guess it just wraps and prevents add/removes?

Comment: Yes, the `Collections.unmodifiableXXX` methods all wrap the given collection. These wrappers delegate to the underlying collection for read operations, but throw `UnsupportedOperationException` for the write operations.

Comment: [The fine documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#unmodview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something must be modifying the underlying set; i.e. the set returned by `node.getOpenPorts()`.

Instead of wrapping the set with an "unmodifiable" wrapper, you could copy it.

```
    final Set<Port> portSet = new HashSet<>(node.getOpenPorts());
```

But as a commenter (@Slaw) pointed out, that just moves the iteration inside the constructor and you would still get CCMEs.

The only real solutions are:

- Change the implementation of the node class to use a concurrent set class for the port list that won't throw CCMEs if the collection is mutated while you are iterating it.
- Change the implementation of the node class to return a *copy* of the port list.  Deal with the updates-while-copying race condition with some internal locking.
- Put a try / catch around the code and repeat the operation if you get a CCME

---

> I've never witnessed this, but I'm getting crash reports from Google.

Yes.  The problem only occurs if this code is executed *while the open port list is changing*.

Comment: Doesn't this just move the iteration to inside `HashSet`? Based on OP's code, the act of copying seems just as likely to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because what I need to do is replace my TreeSet with a ConcurrentSkipListSet.  The `Collections.unmodifiableSet` is not needed. Thanks.